Why does this ink! unit test break rustc?
I wrote a unit test like this:
    #[cfg(test)]
    mod tests {
        use super::*;
        use ink_e2e::{test, DefaultEnvironment};

        #[ink::test]
        fn any_test() {

        }
    }

when running pop test contract I get the following error:
[...]
note: rustc unexpectedly overflowed its stack! this is a bug
note: maximum backtrace depth reached, frames may have been lost
note: we would appreciate a report at https://github.com/rust-lang/rust
help: you can increase rustc's stack size by setting RUST_MIN_STACK=16777216
note: backtrace dumped due to SIGSEGV! resuming signal
error: could not compile `t1` (lib test)
[...]
Error: Failed to execute test command: Cargo test command failed: command ["cargo", "test"] exited with code 101


The issue comes from using
use ink_e2e::{test, DefaultEnvironment};
in a regular unit test.
There are two types of tests in ink! Regular Rust unit tests and ink_e2e tests allow the use of a Substrate runtime. e2e tests are feature gated requiring that it's run with cargo test --features e2e-tests, or with pop-cli pop test contract --e2e
Instead, use ink::env::test and ink::env::DefaultEnvironment when you want to access it in Rust unit tests

Please mark this as the solution if it resolves the question.
